# Kraken API AssetPairs

Tags: trading, hft

I am consuming the Kraken API, and I am not able to find a good explanation to the info I have in the response.

Actually, for a given pair, I have the following info:

```
altname             = alternate pair name
aclass_base         = asset class of base component
base                = asset id of base component
aclass_quote        = asset class of quote component
quote               = asset id of quote component
lot                 = volume lot size
pair_decimals       = scaling decimal places for pair
lot_decimals        = scaling decimal places for volume
lot_multiplier      = amount to multiply lot volume by to get currency volume
leverage_buy        = array of leverage amounts available when buying
leverage_sell       = array of leverage amounts available when selling
fees                = fee schedule array in [volume, percent fee] tuples
fees_maker          = maker fee schedule array in [volume, percent fee] tuples (if on maker/taker)
fee_volume_currency = volume discount currency
margin_call         = margin call level
margin_stop         = stop-out/liquidation margin level
```

I have some questions about this payload. Thanks to everyone who will help.

1. `lot_decimals` and `pair_decimals`: how do these apply ? I am guessing that maybe the former means that the *quantity* of the first currency can be represented with a maximum of `lot_decimals` decimals, with the latter meaning that you can represent the pair value with a maximum of *pair_decimals* decimals. Is this any reasonable ?
2. `lot_multiplier`: the explanation is clear, but it's always 1. Any reason for this being there ?
3. `lot`: is this the amount of first currency that you want to calculate in the second currency ? Example: 100 EURBTC, 100 is the lot size ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bruno, you can answer your own question so that the answer would not be inside the question. I will paste it as an answer, for now. Please let me know in the comments when you are done.

Answer (score 3):

I copied this over from inside the question by @Bruno Ripa:

I had feedback from Kraken. It is:

1. **`lot_decimals`** is the maximal precision of order size (volume), which is in base currency. **`pair_decimals`** is price precision
2. **`lot_multiplier`** is *unused* at the moment.
3. **`lot`**: pair is BTC/EUR, the volume of 100 is denominated in BTC, which is a base currency